# Neo4j: Shortest Path based on Property

Tags: neo4j

Suppose I want to calculate the shortest path of a graph with Neo4j's built-in shortestPath algorithm. Is there a way to use the algorithm where the distance between nodes is encoded in a property of the relationship?

What I mean, in case it is not clear is the following: my graph G consists of 3 vertices A, B, C and 3 edges:

- E1: (A)-->(B)
- E2: (A)-->(C)
- E3: (C)-->(B)

If I ask for the shortest path between A and B in this graph I get E1. However, if the "distance" properties of the edges are as follows, then I would want to get E2-E3 as the shortest path:

- E1: distance = 10
- E2: distance = 4
- E3: distance = 3

Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dijkstra` instead of `shortestPath`, it allows you to specify a `cost_property`. More info can be found [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-graph-algos.html#rest-api-execute-a-dijkstra-algorithm-with-weights-on-relationships)

Comment: Great, thanks. Had I read that page to the bottom I might have figured that one out too ;-)

Comment: It's okay, easy enough to overlook. Happy Graphing!